# converting uchar to int then to string causes crash

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to write pixel values of an image in RGB to a file with Opencv. Basically file will be made of values like

R-G-B

125-12-54

4-47-203

There is nothing wrong with the image, display program shows it without any problems. Here's the relevant portion of the code.

```
Mat rawData = Mat(1, elementcount, CV_8UC1, UArray);
image = imdecode(rawData, IMREAD_COLOR);
...
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int t = 0; t < cols; t++){
            Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(rows, cols);
            ImageValueToString(intensity);
```

I've tried the following but everytime the program crashes

```
void ImageValueToString(Vec3b imagevalue){
   int blue = imagevalue.val[0];
   string blue_string = to_string(blue); // Crash

void ImageValueToString(Vec3b imagevalue){
   int blue = static_cast<int>(imagevalue.val[0]);
   string blue_string = to_string(blue); // Crash

void ImageValueToString(Vec3b imagevalue){
   uchar blue = imagevalue.val[0];
   int blue_int = (int)blue;
   string blue_string = to_string(blue_int); // Crash

 void ImageValueToString(Vec3b imagevalue){
   int blue = imagevalue.val[0];
   string s;
   stringstream out;
   out << blue;
   s = out.str(); // crash
```

The program works if I omit string conversion. This works

```
  int red = 5;
  string red_string = to_string(red);
```

But when converted from uchar, int to string conversion doesn't work. I'm baffled. Any suggestions? I must be missing something trival.

Comment: It is not clear, but it looks like you are _casting_ an int array to string? A C-string must be null-terminated.

Comment: You should probably have a look at "format" function, as well as"FileStorage"

Comment: If the crash is happening in the `to_string` function, you probably have heap corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should never work when sleep deprived.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int t = 0; t < cols; t++){
        Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(rows, cols);
```

As you can see, I'm using variables rows and cols instead of i and t which came to bite me a couple of functions later.

Comment: Oops! I saw this immediately, but glad you figured it out!